# Is there a script/command in R or in cluster (terminal) to delete first certain number of letters from each word in each row of a file?

Tags: r

I have an excel file with chromosome locations of genes. However I would like to delete the first 5 characters to get rid of chromosome numbers. So each row will be 333735-333854 instead of chr9:333735-333854. Do you know any script or command for this? Thank you.

Comment: Sound like something for sed or just find/replace in Excel, not R (unless you're planning on working in R later on).

Answer (score 1):

As an excel person, the formula below does it if the data is in column A

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(":",A1))
```

the formula starts from the right and gives you every character up until the ":"

Answer (score 0):

```
substring(x, 6)
#[1] "333735-333854"
or
sub('.*:', '', x)
#[1] "333735-333854"
```